# Copying a Joomla site to a new server and new URL!

Tags: joomla, dns, transfer

I run a company's site and they want the site to be copied to a new server with a new TDL.

So www.company.com will be copied to www.company.co.uk.

(Changes will be made to the .co.uk site once the site has been copied successfully)

So what is the process here?

I assume I should use Akeeba, but is there another step to make sure the TDL settings change along with the server?

Comment: So what is the problem? Copy all files from one server to another using FTP, copy database(you may use phpmyadmin or some another dumper to dump/restore database), change settings in `configuration.php` and `.htaccess`(if it is used). If I'm not right tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you **only** changes the domain name ? , if so you can have a redirect to `www.company.com -> www.company.co.uk.`

**Manual way**

if you migrate the whole server login in to current Cpanel and download all the site files using **FTP** and generate the mysql scripts from the **phpmyadmin**

Upload the files to ur new server and run the sql script 
(last make sure to update the `configration.php` file with new server names and autehtication details)

Comment: What? No. I'm not redirecting. I need to copy the site exactly and then after it is a 100% copy I will make changes to differentiate the two sites. It's like a transfer but with a new domain as well as new server

Comment: if im doing this action i will prefer the manual way as above :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use Akeeba, you don't need to change anything. Joomla does not have the URL coded anywhere it is calculated by the code. We move sites to different servers all the time with Akeeba, it shouldn't take more than 10-15 minutes to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

1. copy all files to the new location
2. update configuration.php as menioned above (mainly for livesite URL and database user info)
3. check .htaccess if it contains canonicalisation redirects that need to be adjusted
4. make an SQL dump of the database
5. check within the SQL dump if there are internal hyperlinks that need to be adjusted (because Joomla articles may contain references to the site URL)
6. ensure the database user account exists on the target system
7. import the SQL dump

Good luck